# Laravel carry custom values from Controller to Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, single-sign-on, google-authentication, laravel-socialite

I want to restrict certain page to the users who either are viewing the page from certain IP ranges or they have valid Google SSO authenticated account.

Now I have done all the steps of installing and configuring the Socialite plugin and I intend to manage storing and retrieval of any custom values(eg. google_id / google_user_email) using PHP/Laravel Session instead of DB.

But the problem is when I try to pass the newly created custom session value from Controller to Middleware it doesn't work beacause maybe the Session values are reset when redirecting back to Middleware.

Below are the Middleware and Controller files respectively which I have:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Contracts\CustomContract;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class PageMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Valid IP Ranges for Logs module.
     */
    private const VALID_CIDRs = [
        'x.x.x.x/x',
        'y.y.y.y/y',
        ....
    ];

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
         var_dump($request->session()->get('google_user_email'));die;
        $site = resolve(CustomContract::class)->getViewDirectoryName();
        if ($request->getRequestUri() == '/logs' && !self::isIpInCidrs($request->ip(), self::VALID_CIDRs)) {
            return redirect('/auth/google');
            // return response()->view($site.'.errors.403', [], 403);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if a given IP address matches the specified CIDR subnet/s
     *
     * @param string $ip The IP address to check
     * @param mixed $cidrs The IP subnet (string) or subnets (array) in CIDR notation
     * @param string $match optional If provided, will contain the first matched IP subnet
     * @return boolean TRUE if the IP matches a given subnet or FALSE if it does not
     */
    private static function isIpInCidrs($ip, $cidrs, &$match = null)
    {
        foreach ((array) $cidrs as $cidr) {
            list($subnet, $mask) = explode('/', $cidr);
            if (((ip2long($ip) & ($mask = ~ ((1 << (32 - $mask)) - 1))) == (ip2long($subnet) & $mask))) {
                $match = $cidr;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use App\Contracts\CustomContract;

// use Auth;
use Session;
use Socialite;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/administration';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function redirectToGoogle()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from Google.
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handleGoogleCallback(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
        $request->session()->put('google_user_email', $user->email);
        return redirect('logs');

        $site = resolve(CustomContract::class)->getViewDirectoryName();
        return response()->view($site.'.errors.403', [], 403);
    }
}
```

Not able to access the `google_user_email` value into the Middleware stated above.

Can anyone help figuring why the Session resets when redirecting back to Middleware ? And how to pass the new generated session value to middleware from controller ?

Comment: This does not make sense. middlewares are called before the controller function is executed, so you cannot send data to middleware from a controller.

Comment: No it's not like that, Middleware is called twice, once when any user accesses the /page url and other after the Google SSO is authenticated and Conntroller redirects user to /page url again, I have set the `google_user_email` in Controller in Session, but I am never getting it's value in Middleware when it executes on second pass, because the Session is reset, which should never happen as per Session concepts...

Comment: @VickyDev I would need to see some proof of that. AFAIK middleware runs before the controller is even touched.